# Код выдает два верных, но разных ответа на разных компьютерах

Tags: c++

Два одинаковых кода при запуске на двух разных компьютерах выдают два верных ответа, которые выглядят по-разному. Как это можно объяснить? Цель программы - посчитать А+В.Input: 1000000000 1000000000. Output-1: 2000000000. Output-2: 2e+009

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
ifstream cin("input.txt");
ofstream cout("output.txt");
int a, b;
cin » a » b;
cout « a + b;
return 0;
}
```

Попробовал код:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << (int)2000000000;
    return 0;
}
```

Выводится как 2000000000.

Сейчас попробовал снова этот же код в другом документе открыть, теперь выводиться как 2000000000. С чем это связано непонятно, но все теперь нормально, спасибо всем за помощь.

Comment: Вы, наверное, очень удивитесь, но 2000000000 и 2e+009 это одно и то же число. 2e+009 = 2 * 10^9. Просто у Вас настройки локали на компьютерах разные.

Comment: Почитайте про [форматированный ввод/вывод][1]

[1]:http://cppstudio.com/post/319/

Comment: @Alexander Dimov, какая ОС, компилятор и т.д.?

Или откомпилировали в одном месте, а запускали в другом?

Comment: @avp На одном Win7 ultimate и GCC 4.7, на втором Win7 Enterprise и GCC 3.4.5/

Comment: Хм. Странно, что `int` выдаётся в экспоненциальном формате. Похоже на ошибку. Вы уверены, что ваши переменные имеют _оба раза_ тип `int`? Или ваш код — часть бóльшей программы?

Comment: @Alexander Dimov: А попробуйте такую программу:

    #include <iostream>
    int main() {
        std::cout << (int)2000000000;
        return 0;
    }

---
(У вас закончился лимит комментариев, стирайте старые или редактируйте вопрос.)

Comment: Нндааааа... 

Ну, а что еще ждать от винды с крестами?

--

Если серьезно (и на самом деле исходник одинаковый), то действительно загадка. 

Наверное все дело в локали, как указал @Donil.

Comment: @avp: Не, тут что-то не так. Значение `(int)2000000000` должно выводиться одинаково, откуда `cout` знает, каким путём оно получилось?

@Alexander Dimov: уже интереснее. А попробуйте так:

    #include <iostream>
    int main() {
        int a = 1000000000, b = 1000000000;
        cout << a + b;
        return 0;
    }

на той машине, которая выдавала `2e+009`.

Comment: Так же, 2000000000.

Comment: @Alexander Dimov: Всё страньше и страньше. А если так:

    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    int main() {
        ifstream cin("input.txt");
        int a, b;
        cin >> a >> b;
        std::cout << a + b;
        return 0;
    }

(с тем же контентом в input.txt)?

Comment: @VladD Да, с тем же.

Comment: @Alexander Dimov, так что, эффект пропал?

--

@VladD, я понимаю, что если компилятор (функция библиотеки компилятора) честно формирует поток символов, то наблюдаемое явление необъяснимо.

Если же компилятор в конце-концов вызывает `fprintf()`, то будет выполняться функция из *локальной .dll*

У меня был опыт, когда виндовый `printf` (транслировал gcc из MinGW) неправильно выводил некоторые значения `long long`.

Comment: @avp Писал в CodeBlocks все, открыл новый проект и копировал старый код, то все стало нормально, открывая старый проект, то эффект этот остается в нем.

Comment: @Alexander Dimov: тогда, возможно, проблема в том, что проект не компилируется вовремя. Попробуйте вручную удалить исполняемый файл на старом проекте и запустите снова (чтобы файл гарантировано был «свежий»).

Answer (score 1):

Поизучайте [форматированный вывод `cout`](http://kvodo.ru/urok-10-formatirovannyiy-vvod-vyivod-v-c.html). В данном случае Вам нужен параметр `fixed`: `cout.setf(ios::fixed);`